# Css break div in some unknown reason

Tags: html, css

I am trying to view some image width with 100% width.And Inner div should be 25%.When I will zoom in div wont be break.How can I do this.I am giving my html,css code below :

HTML :

```
<div class="container-a1">
        <ul class="caption-style-1">
            <li>
             <div class="hover-effect">
                           <div class="opacity"><img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/td1.png" alt="" width="225px" height="127px"></div>
                         <h1><a href="#">Styling & Detangling</a></h1>
                             <br/>
                           </div>
               <div class="caption">
                      <div class="caption-text">
                    <img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/td2.png" alt="" width="225px" height="127px">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
             <div class="hover-effect">
                           <div class="opacity"><img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/tb1.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px"></div>
                         <h1><a href="#">Smoothing, Shining & Texturizing</a></h1>
                             <br/>
                           </div>
               <div class="caption">
                      <div class="caption-text">
                    <img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/tb2.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>

                        <li>
             <div class="hover-effect">
                           <div class="opacity"><img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/ta1.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px"></div>
                         <h1><a href="#">Curling & Straightening</a></h1>
                             <br/>
                           </div>
               <div class="caption">
                      <div class="caption-text">
                    <img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/ta2.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>

 <li>
             <div class="hover-effect">
                           <div class="opacity"><img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/tc1.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px"></div>
                         <h1><a href="#">Hair Brush Sets</a></h1>
                             <br/>
                           </div>
               <div class="caption">
                      <div class="caption-text">
                    <img src="http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/wp-content/themes/diggsdesign_1/images/tc2.png" alt="" width="235px" height="127px">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.container-a1
{
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}


.caption-text {

     }

   .caption-style-1{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    .caption-style-1 li{
        float: left;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    }

    .caption-style-1 li:hover .caption{
        opacity: 1;
    }

.caption-style-1 .hover-effect{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right:9px; /* L */
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width:225px; /* L */ /* Tiles size */ 
    height:127px; /* L */ /* Tiles size */ 
    background-color:#a3876f; /* Inactive BG Color */ /* L */
    margin-bottom:25px; /* L */
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; /* L */
    }

.hover-effect img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 4;
    }

.hover-effect h1 {
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:300;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:999;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    margin:50px 0px;
    padding:0px; /* L */
    text-align:center;
        width:233px;        
}
.hover-effect p {
    font-size:0.82em; /* Description Font Size */ /* L */
    font-weight:400; /* L */
    font-style:italic; /* L */
    /* margin:63px 22px 0px; /* L */
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    margin-top:100px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    margin:50px 0px; /* L */
}
.hover-effect a,.hover-effect p {
    margin:74px 0px; padding:0px; /* L */
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff; /* Text Color */ /* L */
    text-shadow:0 1px 2px #6e5743; /* L */
}
.caption-style-1 li:hover h1,   .caption-style-1 li:hover p{
   opacity:0;
}
.caption-style-1 .caption{
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        background-color:#ffffff !important; /* L */
}
.caption-style-1 .blur{
        /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);*/
        height: 150px;
        width: 220px;
        z-index: 5;
        position: absolute;
}
.caption-style-1 .caption-text h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.caption-style-1 .caption-text .blur{
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);  
}
```

Comment: what you mean zoom in??

Comment: I mean when you increate your browser size.That means if you change the resolution 800*600.I think you got my point

Comment: if you are working with percentage %, then zooming in your screen ( or changing resolution) it will break of course the Divs since there is no space to continue. because you are using 100% for wrapper and float:left for inner with no width. So nothing wrong.